# how to build grpc shared library with bazel

Tags: c++, grpc, bazel

I'm trying to build shared grpc library with bazel on windows (C++), building with

```
    bazel build :all
```

but in the [BUILD.md](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/BUILDING.md) file, there is no description about how to build shared library by bazel, or build debug, or install.

So how to build && install with bazel? How to config shared library with bazel?

Comment: [Read the docs](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/BUILDING.md#building-with-bazel-recommended)

Comment: @Roy2511 The docs do not explain how to install with Bazel.